# How could I read the first response of the http stream request

Tags: ruby, docker

When I make a request for `curl http://localhost:7788/containers/sampe/stats` in ruby script.

It will get an http stream receiving data every second. The request won't be disconnected.

How could I disconnect the request after  getting the first  response in JSON format with `Ruby`

```
{"read":"2015-07-17T15:47:20.253706054+08:00","network":{"rx_bytes":1526,"rx_packets":19,"rx_errors":0,"rx_dropped":0,"tx_bytes":738,"tx_packets":9,"tx_errors":0,"tx_dropped":0},"precpu_stats":{"cpu_usage":{"total_usage":0,"percpu_usage":null,"usage_in_kernelmode":0,"usage_in_usermode":0},"system_cpu_usage":0,"throttling_data":{"periods":0,"throttled_periods":0,"throttled_time":0}},"cpu_stats":{"cpu_usage":{"total_usage":1024776164,"percpu_usage":[180823377,321637272,276090785,246224730],"usage_in_kernelmode":240000000,"usage_in_usermode":560000000},"system_cpu_usage":19962290000000,"throttling_data":{"periods":0,"throttled_periods":0,"throttled_time":0}},"memory_stats":{"usage":90214400,"max_usage":90451968,"stats":{"active_anon":34742272,"active_file":9658368,"cache":55472128,"hierarchical_memory_limit":1073741824,"inactive_anon":0,"inactive_file":45813760,"mapped_file":30703616,"pgfault":12415,"pgmajfault":286,"pgpgin":23508,"pgpgout":1483,"rss":34742272,"rss_huge":0,"total_active_anon":34742272,"total_active_file":9658368,"total_cache":55472128,"total_inactive_anon":0,"total_inactive_file":45813760,"total_mapped_file":30703616,"total_pgfault":12415,"total_pgmajfault":286,"total_pgpgin":23508,"total_pgpgout":1483,"total_rss":34742272,"total_rss_huge":0,"total_unevictable":0,"total_writeback":0,"unevictable":0,"writeback":0},"failcnt":0,"limit":1073741824},"blkio_stats":{"io_service_bytes_recursive":[],"io_serviced_recursive":[],"io_queue_recursive":[],"io_service_time_recursive":[],"io_wait_time_recursive":[],"io_merged_recursive":[],"io_time_recursive":[],"sectors_recursive":[]}}

{"read":"2015-07-17T15:47:20.253706054+08:00","network":{"rx_bytes":1526,"rx_packets":19,"rx_errors":0,"rx_dropped":0,"tx_bytes":738,"tx_packets":9,"tx_errors":0,"tx_dropped":0},"precpu_stats":{"cpu_usage":{"total_usage":0,"percpu_usage":null,"usage_in_kernelmode":0,"usage_in_usermode":0},"system_cpu_usage":0,"throttling_data":{"periods":0,"throttled_periods":0,"throttled_time":0}},"cpu_stats":{"cpu_usage":{"total_usage":1024776164,"percpu_usage":[180823377,321637272,276090785,246224730],"usage_in_kernelmode":240000000,"usage_in_usermode":560000000},"system_cpu_usage":19962290000000,"throttling_data":{"periods":0,"throttled_periods":0,"throttled_time":0}},"memory_stats":{"usage":90214400,"max_usage":90451968,"stats":{"active_anon":34742272,"active_file":9658368,"cache":55472128,"hierarchical_memory_limit":1073741824,"inactive_anon":0,"inactive_file":45813760,"mapped_file":30703616,"pgfault":12415,"pgmajfault":286,"pgpgin":23508,"pgpgout":1483,"rss":34742272,"rss_huge":0,"total_active_anon":34742272,"total_active_file":9658368,"total_cache":55472128,"total_inactive_anon":0,"total_inactive_file":45813760,"total_mapped_file":30703616,"total_pgfault":12415,"total_pgmajfault":286,"total_pgpgin":23508,"total_pgpgout":1483,"total_rss":34742272,"total_rss_huge":0,"total_unevictable":0,"total_writeback":0,"unevictable":0,"writeback":0},"failcnt":0,"limit":1073741824},"blkio_stats":{"io_service_bytes_recursive":[],"io_serviced_recursive":[],"io_queue_recursive":[],"io_service_time_recursive":[],"io_wait_time_recursive":[],"io_merged_recursive":[],"io_time_recursive":[],"sectors_recursive":[]}}
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to share your code so far.

Comment: just run this as system command in ruby `curl http://localhost:7788/containers/sampe/stats` :(

Answer (score 1):

According to Docker Remote API, you can make a request for `curl http://localhost:7788/containers/sampe/stats?stream=0` then it will only pull one result and disconnect.